# How to configure tripwire to ignore certain files?

Tags: linux, unix, security

I run tripwire daily, I wish to make `tripwire --check` ignore certain files and directories. How can I do it?

Answer (score 9):

You gotta specify a stop point. On the text version of the policy file, it would look like this:

```
!/srv/ro/myfile1.txt ;
!/srv/ro/myfile2.txt ;
```

For more information search for "stop" at "man twpolicy"